# In Bitcask, how is the index/hashtable in memory updated after the old files are merged and compacted?

Tags: nosql, storage, riak

In Bitcask, when a write happens:

1. Data is appended to a file
2. A hashtable in memory is updated with the pointer to the data.

When a read happens for a key:

1. The file and offset is found from the hashtable
2. A random seek IO is used to get the data.

These files are segmented and later merged and compacted to remove obsolete data. After merge, how is the hashtable updated to point to the new merged file? When does it happen? What happens to the read requests at that point?

Answer (score 3):

The compaction is handled by the same process that maintains the hash table.  When a file needs to be compacted, it scans the hash table for key/value pairs that are stored in the file to be compacted, reads and then rewrites the value in the same manner as if a user had updated the value.

This results in the new value being written to a new file, and the hash table is updated as each key is written.

This means that the hash table is never out of date, so get requests don't need to be concerned with whether or not a compaction is in progress.